# Simple quantity function problems, shopping cart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopping-cart, agile

I just picked up Agile Web Development with Rails 3rd Ed., and I'm going thru the Depot Application chapters, I'm attempting to create a simple Edit quantity function, and delete function. I've had luck with the delete function but no luck with the edit quantity function.

I'm going to provide a lot of information, so please don't feel overwhelmed. I've found this to be a challenging problem.

**To add_to_cart.html.erb**

```
<div class="cart-title">Your cart</div>

<table>
<% for item in @cart.items %>
<tr>

<td><% form_for @cart.items, :url => {:action => "cart_update", :id => "#{item.getinventoryid}"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :quantity, :size => '3' %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :id, :value => "#{item.getinventoryid}" %>
  <%= f.submit 'cart_update' %>
<% end %></td>

<td><%=h item.quantity %> &times;</td>
<td><%=h item.title %></li></td>
<td><%=h item.description %></td>
<td class="item-price"><%= number_to_currency(item.price) %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'remove', {:controller => 'inventories', :action => 'remove_cart_item', :id => "#{item.getinventoryid}"} %></td>


</tr>
<% end %>

<tr class="total-line">
<td colspan="4">Total</td>
<td class="total-cell"><%= number_to_currency(@cart.total_price) %></td>
</tr>
</table>

<%= button_to "Checkout", :action => 'checkout' %>
<%= button_to 'Empty cart', :action => 'empty_cart' %>
```

**inventories_controller:**

```
def cart_update
        @inventory = Inventory.find(params[:id])
        @cart = find_cart
        @cart.increment_inventory_quantity(params[:inventory])
    end

    def remove_cart_item
        inventory = Inventory.find(params[:id])
        @cart = find_cart
        @cart.remove_inventory(inventory)
        redirect_to_index("The item was removed")
    end
```

**Cart.rb model**

`attr_accessor :items`

```
def increment_inventory_quantity(id, quantity)
   inventory_to_increment = @items.select{|item| item.inventory == inventory}

   # We do this because select will return an array
   unless product_to_increment.empty?
      inventory_to_increment = inventory_to_increment.first
   else
      # error handling here
   end

   inventory_to_increment.quantity = quantity
end

def remove_inventory(inventory)
   @items.delete_if {|item| item.inventory == inventory }
end
```

**cart_item.rb model**

`attr_accessor :inventory, :quantity`

```
def getinventoryid
        @inventory.id
    end
```

This produces strange results:
[image]

Notice the quantity **16** appears in both items from my loop (#Fail). When I submit the form a ArgumentError in InventoriesController#**cart_update** wrong number of arguments (1 for 2) error is returned. Parameters being passed:

```
{"commit"=>"cart_update",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"sH1tWXTJPltpSq5XaAkww7259IR5ZiflnqSFB2Zb0IY=",
 "id"=>"50",
 "cart_item"=>{"quantity"=>"16",
 "id"=>"50"}}
```

Comment: Hi JZ - a couple of questions.  First, how is @inventory being set in the cart_item model?  Second, can you provide more info on the "wrong number of arguments" error?  It would help to know what method was throwing that error.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jamie, I've updated the error above; the error comes from the cart_update method. The fix below worked in terms of correcting the proper units displayed, however my method is still producing the wrong number of arguments error. 

In terms of @Inventory in my cart_item:

def initialize( inventory )
  @inventory = inventory
  @quantity = 1
end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the wrong number of arguments error because you are passing one argument to `@cart.increment_inventory_quantity` in the controller method. That method requires two arguments.

```
# In your controller:
def cart_update
  @inventory = Inventory.find(params[:id])
  @cart = find_cart
  @cart.increment_inventory_quantity(params[:inventory]) # you are passing one thing
end
# Then in your model:
def increment_inventory_quantity(id, quantity) # the method wants two things
  # ...
```

Possibly you intended to do something like this:

```
def cart_update
  @inventory = Inventory.find(params[:cart_item][:id])
  @cart = find_cart
  @cart.increment_inventory_quantity(@inventory.id, params[:cart_item][:quantity])
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's form_for( @cart.items ) and not form_for( item )?

Comment: Thanks that corrects the displayed quantities - I'm still having issues with the cart_update method; Its still producing the wrong number of arguments error.